# Convert a date in GTM String format to a date object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java

From Java I need to set a cookie expiry time to cookie content instead of setting a expiry time to this cookie. Following code shows how this was done.

```
public static Cookie addOPBrowserStateCookie(HttpServletResponse response) {

    int expiresSeconds = 120;
    Date date = new Date();
    date = new Date(date.getTime() +1000 * expiresSeconds);
    String expiryTime = date.toGMTString();
    Cookie cookie =
            new Cookie(OIDCSessionConstants.OPBS_COOKIE_ID, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_" + expiryTime);
    cookie.setSecure(true);
    cookie.setPath("/");

    response.addCookie(cookie);
    return cookie;
}
```

Then from Javascript I need to convert this String back to a date object and compare with the current date value. Following is the way I tried to do that.

```
    function getOPBrowserState() {
        var name = "opbs=";
        var cookie = document.cookie + ";";
        var start = cookie.indexOf(name);
        if (start != -1) {
            var end = cookie.indexOf(";", start);
            opbs = cookie.substring(start + name.length, end);
        }

        console.log(opbs);
        var c = opbs.split('_');
        var result = c[0];
        var expiry_time = Date.parse(c[1]);
        var now = Date.now();
        console.log(expiry_time.toString());

        if (expiry_time < now) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return result;
        }

    }
```

However when I use Date.parse on the String I keep getting Nan value for the expire_date. Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `c[1]` contains? With `new Date()` should work if you pass GMT string to it.

Comment: it is the GMT string i set from Java for the cookie content, e.g. "31 May 2018 07:24:01 GMT"

Comment: `new Date("31 May 2018 07:24:01 GMT");` should work

Comment: Thanks! Yes this worked. However, problem was, when splitting the 'opbs' string, randomly a double quote was appended to the end of the string. Hence I got the Nan result before.